delete ONLY alternate consecutive rows based on a column value
I have a bit of a problem with my dataset. I am trying to delete the consecutive rows but only in an alternate way!
so in the dataset below, group ABCDE should delete 2,4 and 6 based on column ID
my data
group   ID  
ABCDE   2   
ABCDE   3   
ABCDE   4   
ABCDE   5   
ABCDE   6   
ABCDE   22  

I have tried couple things but fail to keep the alternate rows, it is deleting all consecutive ones. Thanks in advance
Output I am looking is to retain the "keep" only;
 group  ID  result
    
    ABCDE   3   Keep
    ABCDE   5   Keep
    ABCDE   22  Keep
    


your question is incomplete. So which rows need to be deleted? Show the results you want

data.query("reults != 'delete'") or even data.loc[data['results'] != 'delete']

to solve this problem you can have a boolean flag (can_keep_value):

when there are consecutive values, this flag will alternate (not can_keep_value)
when there are no consecutive values, this flag will always be True

here is a sample code
data = [19, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 22, 18, 21, 22, 23]
filtered_data = []
can_keep_value = True

for i, value in enumerate(data):
    # First element is always appended to filtered list
    if i == 0:
        filtered_data.append(value)
        can_keep_value = True
        continue

    # If current value is a sequence of previous value
    is_consecutive_value = value == data[i - 1] + 1

    # Is is a consecutive value, must alternate
    if is_consecutive_value:
        can_keep_value = not can_keep_value
    # If is not consecutive, can always add to the list
    else:
        can_keep_value = True

    if can_keep_value:
        filtered_data.append(value)

# Output: [19, 2, 4, 6, 22, 18, 21, 23]
print(filtered_data)

